# Paragraph in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, paragraphs

How make paragraph in TikZ. I use \parbox with \node

```
\node {\parbox[5cm]{text}};
```

but i need more options, alignment center or left or right, similar to text box. All in TikZ.

thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are some differences between TikZ versions.

- With TikZ/pgf 2.10 use the alignment options given by Torbjorn: `align=left` etc. as options to `\node`. This doesn't work with TikZ 2.00. Example:

  ```
  \node[text width=3cm,align=right] {your text};
  ```
- With TikZ/pgf 2.00 or below use `text` options to `\node` such as `text centered`, `text ragged` or `text badly ragged.` Example:

  ```
  \tikz \draw (0,0) node[text width=3cm,text ragged] {your text}
  ```
- You may always use the vertical alignment options of `\parbox` and horizontal alignment declarations within the box.

  Syntax: `\parbox[position][height][inner-pos]{width}{text}`

  Example: `\node{\parbox[t][6cm][c][5cm]{\centering your text}};`

Comment: Thanks! And justify in TikZ/PGF 2.00? And break line with \\?

Comment: @Regis da Silva: option `text justified`, and just use \\. Example: `\node[text width=2cm,text justified] {Test\\text and more text};`

Answer (score 11):

See section 16.4 in the TikZ manual. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for creating dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [text width=5cm,align=left] {\lipsum[1]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Other alignment options are `center` and `right` (naturally), as well as `flush left`, `flush center` and `flush right`, in which no hyphenation will occur, and `justify`.