# Flowchart generated with tikz is too big for the slide - How to adjust the size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I generated a flowchart using tikz. The flowchart is way too big for the slide as seen on the attached picture.  [image: Attached picture].

```
\begin{frame}[c]{Hypothesis}
    \begin{itemize}
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
\bigskip
    \item \bfseries What are the determinants of Daimler's success? \\
\bigskip
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=1pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Flowchart: Preparation [id:dp16708666218127965] 
\draw   (110,140) -- (125,120) -- (175,120) -- (190,140) -- (175,160) -- (125,160) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da008706334500105495] 
\draw    (190,140) -- (358,140) ;
\draw [shift={(360,140)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp20222409952627096] 
\draw   (480,128) .. controls (480,123.58) and (483.58,120) .. (488,120) -- (542,120) .. controls (546.42,120) and (550,123.58) .. (550,128) -- (550,152) .. controls (550,156.42) and (546.42,160) .. (542,160) -- (488,160) .. controls (483.58,160) and (480,156.42) .. (480,152) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp4672435896265028] 
\draw   (10,88) .. controls (10,83.58) and (13.58,80) .. (18,80) -- (72,80) .. controls (76.42,80) and (80,83.58) .. (80,88) -- (80,112) .. controls (80,116.42) and (76.42,120) .. (72,120) -- (18,120) .. controls (13.58,120) and (10,116.42) .. (10,112) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp614218290405953] 
\draw   (10,168) .. controls (10,163.58) and (13.58,160) .. (18,160) -- (72,160) .. controls (76.42,160) and (80,163.58) .. (80,168) -- (80,192) .. controls (80,196.42) and (76.42,200) .. (72,200) -- (18,200) .. controls (13.58,200) and (10,196.42) .. (10,192) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp8576301850793258] 
\draw   (210,208) .. controls (210,203.58) and (213.58,200) .. (218,200) -- (322,200) .. controls (326.42,200) and (330,203.58) .. (330,208) -- (330,232) .. controls (330,236.42) and (326.42,240) .. (322,240) -- (218,240) .. controls (213.58,240) and (210,236.42) .. (210,232) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da0197418685889148] 
\draw    (80,180) -- (108.8,141.6) ;
\draw [shift={(110,140)}, rotate = 126.87] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da40531294332746337] 
\draw    (80,100) -- (108.8,138.4) ;
\draw [shift={(110,140)}, rotate = 233.13] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Flowchart: Preparation [id:dp6374806448271275] 
\draw   (360,140) -- (375,120) -- (425,120) -- (440,140) -- (425,160) -- (375,160) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp7690789682331358] 
\draw   (570,88) .. controls (570,83.58) and (573.58,80) .. (578,80) -- (632,80) .. controls (636.42,80) and (640,83.58) .. (640,88) -- (640,112) .. controls (640,116.42) and (636.42,120) .. (632,120) -- (578,120) .. controls (573.58,120) and (570,116.42) .. (570,112) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp3837336797542996] 
\draw   (570,168) .. controls (570,163.58) and (573.58,160) .. (578,160) -- (632,160) .. controls (636.42,160) and (640,163.58) .. (640,168) -- (640,192) .. controls (640,196.42) and (636.42,200) .. (632,200) -- (578,200) .. controls (573.58,200) and (570,196.42) .. (570,192) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da1421316570299238] 
\draw    (440,140) -- (478,140) ;
\draw [shift={(480,140)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8090528149307497] 
\draw    (550,140) -- (569.11,101.79) ;
\draw [shift={(570,100)}, rotate = 116.57] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da828335614226529] 
\draw    (550,140) -- (569.11,178.21) ;
\draw [shift={(570,180)}, rotate = 243.43] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8402367846778058] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (270,200) -- (270,142) ;
\draw [shift={(270,140)}, rotate = 90] [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da7961277540972509] 
\draw    (400,120) .. controls (432.84,26.97) and (100.35,29.47) .. (159.08,118.65) ;
\draw [shift={(160,120)}, rotate = 235.16] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da6145683751975906] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (270,200) .. controls (309.4,170.45) and (276.03,87.05) .. (270.24,51.59) ;
\draw [shift={(270,50)}, rotate = 81.75] [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

% Text Node
\draw (21,92) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Capital};
% Text Node
\draw (21,172) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Labor};
% Text Node
\draw (201,122) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\footnotesize Transformation \ \ Process}};
% Text Node
\draw (371,131) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Outputs};
% Text Node
\draw (221,211) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Human Capital};
% Text Node
\draw (575,172) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\small Societal }};
% Text Node
\draw (484,132) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Success};
% Text Node
\draw (573,91) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\small Corporate }};
% Text Node
\draw (258,161) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {+};
% Text Node
\draw (448,122) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {+};
% Text Node
\draw (558,132) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {+};
% Text Node
\draw (126,132) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {Inputs};
% Text Node
\draw (91,132) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {+};
% Text Node
\draw (231,31) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\footnotesize Feedback \ Loop}};
% Text Node
\draw (291,161) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,opacity=1 ] [align=left] {+}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

    
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Scale the tikzpicture as explained in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-including-texts) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/correctly-scaling-a-tikzpicture).

Comment: Welcome to SE. First, can't you just modify the `scale` options given as parameters to your `tikzpicture`? Second, please always provide a Mnimal Working Example. As it is, your code isn't compilable and it's impossible to know which packages you're using.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete, compilable document with your flowchart. Remove in it all what is not related with it and add preamble to your code fragment.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your answer. Sorry, I am new here and just started using Latex. I will provide a reproducible example (that works) the next time I have a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It seems that for writing of your code you use some online generator (in hope, that this is short way to your image)
- Unfortunately, generated code is fill of clutter, so it is not easy to introduce necessary changes, that it can be fint on beamer frame. Consequently I redraw it from scratch ...
- Image is still wider than text area. Therefore I use \small font size (you may further reduce it to `\footnotesize 7 and make nodes narrower).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]
\frametitle{Hypothesis}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.2em}{-2.2em}
\centering
\small
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%x=0.5pt,y=0.5pt,%yscale=-1,
node distance = 2mm and 6mm,
  base/.style = {draw=blue, semithick, minimum width=3.3em, minimum height=3ex,
                 inner ysep=2mm, outer sep=1pt,   
                 execute at end node=\vphantom{g}
                 },  
   box/.style = {base, rounded corners},
    io/.style = {base, inner xsep=-2pt,
                 signal, signal to=west and east,
                 draw, semithick, minimum width=3em},
every edge/.style = {draw, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto,font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                            inner sep=2pt, align=center}
                        ]
%% nodes  
\node (n1a) [box] {Capital};
\node (n2)  [io, below right=of n1a,
             label=left:+]    {inputs};
\node (n1b) [box,below  left=of n2]     {Labor};
\node (n3)  [io, right=24mm of n2]      {Outputs};
\node (n4)  [box,right=of n3,
             label=right:+]             {Success};
\node (n5a) [box,above right=of n4]     {Corporate};
\node (n5b) [box,below right=of n4]     {Societal};
%
\node (n6)  [box,below=of {$(n2.south)!0.5!(n3.south)$}]
                                        {Human Capital};
%% arrows 
\path   (n1a.east)  edge (n2)
        (n1b.east)  edge (n2)
        (n2) edge["Transformation\\ Process" 
                  {name=tp}]             (n3)
        (n3) edge["+"]  (n4)
        (n4.east)   edge (n5a.west)
        (n4.east)   edge (n5b.west)
        (n3) edge[bend right=45, 
                  "Feedback\\ Loop" '
                  {name=fl}]            (n2)
                  ;
\path[draw=red, thick]  (n6.north -| tp) edge["+"]  (tp)
                        (n6.north) edge[bend right, 
                                        pos=0.3, "+" ']  (fl)
                        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right I used an online code generator. I thought that would be easier and faster for me as a beginner to design a graph. Your code is awesome, thank you so much. I have to improve further.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestions in the comments that the most straightforward solution would be to decrease the scale.

Another (perhaps clunkier) thing you could do is to split the text "Transformation Process" into two lines, so that the line with that label is shorter.
See here: [Paragraph in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7835/paragraph-in-tikz)

Comment: Yes, I tried to reduce the scale. That works, but the size of the text is not reduced in the same way. So as a result I have a graph that fits the page, but the labels are too big for the graph.